# Use FormsAuthentication.SignOut() in ASMX web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, forms-authentication

I have a web service, let's say User.asmx and it has a method LogoutUser().

Service is consumed by an external website and what I want to do is when user log out from that external website, they will make a call to our service to log out user from my website as well. This is required when user logs into my site he gets redirected to that external website.

Any ideas how would I be able to do it? FormsAuthentication.SignOut() seems to work locally or on my test machine but when client tries to call the service, user doesn't get log out. We cannot avoid using cookie for forms authentication in our website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work this way. If user makes requests to server `A` (external site) and `B` (your site) and has cookies from `A` and `B` and then calls `A` and you expect that `A` calling `B` would make client somehow drop the cookie from `B` then you have a bad time.

Rule is, site `A` is never, ever allowed to manage cookies for site `B`. Plus, you want the user to be signed out, not the partner's web site to be signed out from your web site.

One of the ways to make it work is when user calls `A` (them), then `A` returns an iframe that points to `B` (you) and the resource it points to calls `FormsAuthentication.SignOut`.

Formally, `A` should have the `logoutA.aspx` that returns

```
 <html>
 <body>
    <iframe src="http://b/logoutB.aspx" style="display : none" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

where B should then have `logoutB.aspx` that does `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`.

This way the user gets page from A, the iframe from the page points to B, the browser goes to B and gets signed out.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I was thinking but reluctant to do considering so many redirects for user, first from B to A and then A to B... but yeah I think there is not choice to but to setup a new page that does the logout bit and then redirect user back to site B. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Fortunately `iframes` are handled internally so you don't have to redirect.